# C++ - How to generate every possible combination of n 3D coordinates by incrementing x/y/z by a given value x

Tags: c++, arrays, recursion, vector, 3d

As part of a larger program I need to generate every possible set of 3D coordinate points contained within the rectangular prism formed by the origin and point (Y1, Y2, Y3), given the number of points, n, that will be in the set, and the value by which the x/y/z values are to be incremented by.

This was what I initially wrote, which does the job of cycling through all possible coordinates correctly for an individual point, but does not correctly generate all the overall combinations of points needed.

In the program I created a point object, and created a vector of point objects with default x/y/z values of zero.

```
void allPoints(double Y1, double Y2, double Y3, double increment, vector<Point> pointset)
{
int count = pointset.size()-1;

while (count>=0)
{
    while (pointset.at(count).getX()<Y1) 
    {
        while (pointset.at(count).getY()<Y2)
        {
            while (pointset.at(count).getZ()<Y3)
            {
                //insert intended statistical test to be run on each possible set here 
            }
            pointset.at(count).setZ(0);
            pointset.at(count).incY(increment);
        }
        pointset.at(count).setY(0);
        pointset.at(count).incX(increment);

    }
    count--;
}

}
```

I am new to coding and may be approaching this entirely wrong, and am just looking for help getting in the right direction. If using a point object isn't the way to go, it's not needed in the rest of the program - I could use 3d arrays instead.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets assume you have class `Point3d` which represents a point, `Vec3d` which represents a vector which can translate points (proper operators are defined).
In such case this should go like this:

```
std::vector<Point3d> CrystalNet(
    size_t size,
    const Point3d& origin,
    const Vec3d& a = { 1, 0, 0 },
    const Vec3d& b = { 0, 1, 0 },
    const Vec3d& c = { 0, 0, 1 })
{
    std::vector<Point3d> result;
    result.reserve(size * size * size);

    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    for (int j = 0; j < size; ++j)
    for (int k = 0; k < size; ++k) {
         result.empalce_back(origin + a * i + b * j + c * k);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Defining `Point3d` and `Vec3d` is quite standard and I'm sure there is ready library which can do it.

Answer (score 0):

The chief problem appears to be that your textual description is about *creating* a pointset. The count isn't known up front. The example code takes an already created pointset. That just doesn't work.

That's also why you end up with the `// insert test here` - that's not the location for a test, that's where you would add a new point to the pointset you have to create.

Comment: In my main program I create a points of the right size and set all values to 0, and that's the pointset vector I bring in here. My logic was that from there I would increment all those values, and after each incrementation I would run my desired test. Within that code I'm not adding or removing points, I already have a points of the right size created. Is this still not the general way to approach it?